# How do I change pager (# of items) for one page display in a view?

Tags: views, paging

I have a view that will have about 7 different display pages. Some of the pages will have a different amount of items displayed on that page.

When I'm on my Publication Page (display name) and change `Use pager:Display a specified number of items | 3 items` to `15`, it changes it for all displays in this view.

How do I override it for this display only. Here is a screenshot of the page I'm currently on: https://ibb.co/8YJpC1d

I thought this would be something easy (probably is), but I honestly couldn't find anything online to help me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I answered my own question, when I clicked the left side `Use pager:Display a specified number of items` it let me select if I want to override for just that display.

Comment: Yes it confused me once too. The Override option appears only on the modal where you're choosing the option, and not on the Settings modal of the option, so you have to remember to click on the "left" one if you want to override for that display.